# How to write code coverage for subscribe method with finalize keyword in Angular Jamsine?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, finalize

Angular version: "@angular/core": "6.1.7"

Jamsine version: "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0"

**File name: app.component.ts** (Method inside the component file)

```
testFunction() {
this.testClassService.testServiceFunction(data).pipe(takeWhile(() => this.testModel.subscriberFlag))
  .subscribe((response: string) => {
    console.log('Service covered');
}); 
}
```

**File Name: app.component.service.ts** (Here the testServiceFunction called from above component)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppConfig } from '../../../../config/app.config';
import { AppLocalConfig } from '../../../../config/app.local.config';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class TestClassService {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
    const appConfig: any = (environment.envName === 'local') ? AppLocalConfig.getConfig() : AppConfig.getConfig();
    this.endpoints = appConfig.api;
  }
  testServiceFunction() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**File name: app.component.spec.ts** spec for above testFunction method (Working perfectly)

```
it('spec to cover testFunction', () => {
  const response = 'success';
  spyOn(service, 'testServiceFunction').and.returnValue(of(response));
  component.testFunction();
});
```

**How to write spec for below subscribe method with finalize keyword.?**

```
testFunction() {
this.testClassService.testServiceFunction(data).pipe(takeWhile(() => this.testModel.subscriberFlag))
.pipe(finalize(() => {
    console.log('Finalize covered');
  }))
  .subscribe((response: string) => {
    console.log('Service covered');
  });
}
```

Comment: The same way... ?

Comment: @JB Nizet - That same way not cover those line.. Console not get printed and those lines are shown in red color in chrome browser(from index file inside coverage folder).

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. My guess is that the actual service used in the function is not the one you spied on.

Comment: @JBNizet - I imported, initialized and added inside Testbed (service = TestBed.get(TestService);) -- That has been done properly. Please say how to write code to cover subscribe with finalize keyword..

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet - Here there is no error thrown while running the test case using 'npm run test', but the problem is that those codes not get covered. I need the code sample how to cover finalize method. I don't know how to post a complete minimal example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190436/discussion-between-arunvalaven-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: You write a service, a component, and its test, having the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem. And you post the entire code of all three. I must be able to add the service, the component and the test to a standard basic Angular project, run the test, and see the problem reproduced. So that I can examine why the problem occurs, and make the necessary changes (if I'm able to) to fix the issue.

Comment: @JBNizet -- Added sample service file for better understanding

Comment: Read my previous comment again. Posting an imaginary service that wouldn't make the rest of the code compile is not what "posting a complete minimal example reproducing the problem" is.